# For my code why does it gives comiler error as Cannot convert 'void' to 'bool' as Array.Reverse() is void

Tags: c#

string name = "teknaS";

char[] cArr = name.ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(Array.Reverse(cArr));

Comment: `Array.Reverse` is a method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-5.0 you're trying to write a method out as string. You need to call the method itself then write it to console. So something like `char[] cArr = name.ToArray(); Array.Reverse(cArr);  Console.WriteLine(cArr);`

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` expects a string but you add [`Array.Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Reverse_System_Array_) which is [`void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void), so returns nothing. Instead call `Array.Reverse` before and then use `Console.WriteLine(cArr)`:

```
char[] cArr = name.ToArray();
Array.Reverse(cArr);
Console.WriteLine(cArr);
```

Another option is LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine(name.Reverse().ToArray());
```